# How to compute the expected number of sats to arrive in a probabilistic payment flow?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing

Look at the following network example:

[image]

Assume `S` wants to send `3` sats to `R`. You can further assume that `S` has enough liquidity in each of its local channels to send up to `3` sats. Also assume the liquidity in channels `(A,R), (B,R)` and `(C,R)` is uniformly distributed.

one [optimally reliable payment flow](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.05322) in this diagram looks like this:

```
1 sat: S --> A --> R   probability: 2/3
2 sats: S --> B --> R  probability: 3/5
```

This flow has a total probability of `2/3*3/5 = 2/5 = 0.4 = 40%`

**The question:**

**How to compute the expected value of Satoshis to arrive at `R` if `S` sends `3`?**

**Option A**

(which I already know is wrong but I write it down because I suspect some people might have a similar first thought)

Initially I thought this would just be `3 sats * 2/5 = 6/5 sats = 1.2 sats` which is what one gets from multiplying the amount to send with the probability of the flow. This seems strange as sending 2 sats along `S-->B-->R` has a probability of `3/5` and with the reasoning of above an expectation value of `2 sats * 3/5 = 6/5 sats = 1.2 sats`. as the expected value for 1 sat along the `S-->A-->B` path is larger than `0` this would be a contradiction to the additivity of the expected value.

**Option B**

Starting from the above reasoning we add the expected values for the disjoint paths so:

```
E[3 sats] = 1 sat * 2/3 + 2 sat * 3/5 = 10/15 sats + 18/15 sats = 28/15 sats
```

**Option C**

Of course the 2 satoshi path `S-->B-->R` does not have to be sent as one onion but could be sent as two onions with 1 sat each:

The first has a probability of `4/5` and the second has a conditional probability of `3/4` which is [extensively explained at this issue](https://github.com/lightningdevkit/rust-lightning/issues/1170#issuecomment-972396747). With the logic from option B one should be able to add those expected values.
so we have the expected value for sending two sats in two seperate 1 sat onions along `S--> B --> R` would be computed as:

```
E[2 sats] = 1 sat * 4/5 + 1 sat * 3/4 = 31/20 sats
```

If we add the 1 sat onion from the `S-->A-->R` which was `2/3` sats

we would expect to have

```
E[3 sats] = 31/20 sats + 2/3 sats = 93/60 sats + 40/60 sats = 132/60 sats = 33/15 sats
```

This is `5/15 sats = 1/3 sats` more than the answer in option B

**Option D**

To make things worse I am confused if the expected values of dissecting the 2 sat onion in option C into two 1 sat onions can just linearly added up as the second onion is conditioned on having 2 sats of liquidity in the channel. If the first onion has failed the second one will certainly fail. Thus one would have to compute expected value for sending two 1 sat onions like this:

```
E[2 sats] = 1 sat * 4/5 + 1 sat * 3/5 = 7/5 sats
```

this would result in a total expected value of:

```
E[3 sats] = 2/3 sats + 7/5 sats = 10/30 sats + 21/15 sats = 31/15 sats
```

**Thoughts**

just for comparison here are the results

- **Option A**: `18/15`
- **Option B**: `28/15`
- **Option C**: `33/15`
- **Option D**: `31/15`

While Option B seems certainly right it makes sense to further dissect the 2 sats onion. In simulations I did it seems that Option D is correct which is a bit surprising for me. Using the formalism of probability theory the difference for the 2 sat path is:

- **Option C**: `E[2 sats] = 1 sat * P(X>=1) + 1 sat * P(X>=2 | X >= 1)`
- **Option D**: `E[2 sats] = 1 sat * P(X>=1) + 1 sat * P(X>=2)`

As said the simulated setting indicates that Option D is the correct answer but that is highly surprising to me as I would expect the second term to be a conditional probabilty.

Answer (score 0):

Let's review the definition of expected value.
The expected value of the random variable `X` given the state of the system `O`,
denoted as `E(X,O)` is computed as:

```
E(X,O) = \sum_i p_i(O) X_i
```

The sum is over all *microstates* (all ways in which liquidity could be allocated in the channels) or equivalently one can choose to sum over all possible observable outcomes. The `p_i(O)` is the probability of verifying `i` given the state `O`, and `X_i` is the value that `X` takes if `i` is verified.
Using this definition, one immediately sees that `E(.,O)` is a linear operator:

```
E(X+a*Y,O) = E(X,O) + a*E(Y,O)
```

That would be enough to answer your question.
You get different answers because you have constructed your observables differently.

## Case B

Your observable is the sum of two flows `x` that goes through `S-A-R` with 1 sat and `y` that goes through `S-B-R` with 2 sat.

```
E(x+y,O) = E(x,O) + E(y,O)
```

Now, `x` either fails (prob. 1/3) getting us 0 sat or it succeeds giving us 1 sat (prob. 2/3).

```
E(x,O) = 0*1/3 + 1*2/3 = 2/3
```

Similarly with `y`

```
E(y,O) = 0*2/5 + 2*3/5 = 6/5
```

Adding up to

```
E(x+y,O) = 2/3 + 6/5 = 28/15
```

But be careful, that here we are assuming that `x` outcome is independent of the outcome of `y`. This is the case if you are sending two single path payments.

## Case A

If you instead consider an atomic multi-path payment in which either both `x` and `y` succeed or none will, then the two outcomes for `x` are again 1 sat and 0 sat, but with probabilities 2/3*3/5=2/5 (both `x` and `y` succeed)
and 3/5 (all other cases) respectively:

```
E(x,O)= 1*2/5 + 0*3/5 = 2/5
```

similarly for `y`

```
E(y,O)= 2*2/5 + 0*3/5 = 4/5
```

Adding up to

```
E(x+y,O) = 2/5 + 4/5 = 6/5 = 18/15
```

## Case D

You are building your observable as the sum of three single path flows (non-atomic):
`x` representing 1 sat over `S-A-R`, `y` representing 1 sat over `S-B-R`
and `z` representing 1 sat over `S-B-R` AFTER `y`. This is different from case **B** because `y` and `z` are not attached to each other, `y` might succeed and then `z` could fail.

Usual computations

```
E(x,O) = 0*1/3 + 1*2/3 = 2/3
```

for `y`

```
E(y,O) = 0*1/5 + 1*4/5 = 4/5
```

Then comes `z`, which will succeed only if there is enough liquidity for 2 sats on channel `B-R`, then

```
E(z,O) = 0*2/5 + 1*3/5= 3/5
```

Adding up:

```
E(x+y+z,O) = 2/3+4/5+3/5 = 31/15
```

## Case C

Is similar to case **D** but the math is wrong.
You are correctly computing `E(x,O)=2/3` and `E(y,O)=4/5`, but with
`E(z,O)` you are messing up with the conditional probability.

Let's see all possible outcomes:

- `y` fails, then also `z` fails, prob. 1/5, (having exactly 0 sat liquidity)
- `y` succeeds, but `z` fails, prob. 1/5, (having exactly 1 sat of liquidity)
- `y` succeeds, `z` succeeds, prob. 3/5, (all other cases which correspond to having enough liquidity for 2 sat)
  which is the same as the multiplication of `y` succeeding and the conditional prob. of `z` succeeding after `y` does (3/5 = 4/5 * 3/4).

```
E(z,O) = 0*1/5 + 0*1/5 + 1*3/5 = 3/5
```

It is important to state that `z` is tried after `y` or we get into race conditions.

## Summary

- Case **A** is right if you send a two flow atomic payment,
- Case **B** is right if you send two single path payments,
- Case **C** is wrong,
- Case **D** is right if you send three single path payments.

I am confident that if you run the experiments you'll confirm.